# Magick++ NoDecodeDelegateForThisImageFormat

Tags: imagemagick, magick++

I've googled my problem and found many pages, but none of them have exactly the same flavour and I can't get my problem to go away.

I have a program which uses Magick++ and works fine on my PC, but it fails on another computer where I'm trying to run the code. A minimal example is this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Magick++.h>

int main(){
    Magick::Image im;
    im.read( "/fullpathtoimage.jpg" );
    std::cout<< im.columns() <<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

(where of course "/fullpathtoimage.jpg" is a valid image).

This raises an exception:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Magick::ErrorMissingDelegate'
  what():  ImageMagick: NoDecodeDelegateForThisImageFormat `/fullpathtoimage.jpg' @ constitute.c/ReadImage/503
Aborted
```

Other reports of this problem basically say that they don't have delegates for jpeg, and should install libjpeg etc, but they were getting the same errors when running 'convert'. However, when I do

```
./convert /fullpathtoimage.jpg temp.png
```

It runs perfectly. Doing

```
./identify -list configure
```

lists, amongst others

```
DELEGATES      bzlib mpeg fontconfig freetype jng jpeg pango png ps x xml zlib
LIBS           -lfreetype -ljpeg -lpng12 -lfontconfig -lXext -lXt -lSM -lICE -lX11 -lbz2 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lcairo -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lxml2 -lz -lm
```

and

```
./identify -list format | grep JPEG
```

gives

```
  JNG* rw-   JPEG Network Graphics
 JPEG* rw-   Joint Photographic Experts Group JFIF format (62)
PJPEG* rw-   Joint Photographic Experts Group JFIF format (62)
```

So, all seems fine, all binaries work, just my code doesn't.

The version I installed is ImageMagick-6.8.7-8, I built it from sources as I don't have root access at the machine, and I installed it to a location within my home (using ./configure --prefix=/home/... ). I checked if maybe there's an issue with linking my program against wrong ImageMagick (as there is an older system one too), but ldd reveals all is fine i.e. the program is linked against the one I installed, as I wanted, and running ldd on convert shows it is linked against exactly the same libraries.

Comment: Just a small bump to ask if by any chance you solved your problem, as I encountered exactly the same and found close to nothing on how to fix it.

Comment: @JBL I fixed it but didn't post the fix as, to be honest, I don't quite understand how I did it. I deleted ImageMagick-6.8.7-8, I tried with a slightly older version (e.g. I thought maybe it's some bug in this one), 6.6.0-10 (chose this one as that's the one I have on my computer), and all worked without a problem. Then I deleted that one and installed the new one (6.8.7-8) again and somehow this magically worked too.. I didn't really have the time to investigate what happened, maybe I didn't delete the older one properly. Anyway, try an older version and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Many thanks for your quick response, I'll try that asap.

Comment: that sounds like the .so links in the program don't match what's installed on the machine. Someone might benefit from static linking the binaries. Unfortunately it's too involved for a comment. The file size on the binaries do increase so it's not going to benefit everyone and your solution of downloading matching .so files from the older package is likely the simplest.